# Get loaded assembly based on Full Qualified Name

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Anyone have an idea how to easily parse through loaded assemblies and get an Assembly object based on the full name?

For example, my config has "MyWonderfulApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" and I want to know what "Assembly" that is so I can load it into an AssemblyCatalog in MEF.

NOTE: I understand there are different ways to load so lets keep those answers out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use [AssemblyName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6ccxba0.aspx) for parsing the string from your config file and I guess you'll get the [assemblies loaded in the app domain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.getassemblies.aspx) and filter them comparing the assembly name from config with the result from the assemblies' [Assembly.GetName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3bk16ya.aspx) method.